# Solving a system of linear equations with 3 equations, 3 variables and a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following system of linear equations:

\begin{cases}
(k-1)x+(1-k)z=-4\\
-x+-(2-k)y-z=-6\\
kx+y+z=1+k
\end{cases}

I need to find the values of k for which the system can be compatible or not compatible, so I calculate the determinant of the coefficients matrix and get

$-k^3+2k^2-k$

solving this polynomial, I get two values of k which are 0 and 1. Using Rouchè-Capelli, the system is not compatible for k=1 and it is compatible for k=0

However, according to the solution, there should be a third value which is supposed to be 2, but I don't know how to find it. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: From the first equation we get $$(k-1)(x-z)=-4$$ so we get $$k\neq 1$$
Plugging $$x=\frac{4}{1-k}+z$$ in the third equation we get

$$\frac{4}{1-k}+z-(2-k)y-z=-6$$ so $$-(2-k)y=\frac{6k-10}{1-k}
$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm still a bit lost on how I can find the third value. The 2 might be coming from the second equation, but I don't understand why k should be different than 2.